How to Accurately Determine Real Disk Space Used by Active Backup for Business on Synology NAS
I recently faced an issue when trying to calculate the real disk space consumed by a backup task in Active Backup for Business on a Synology NAS. Traditional methods like du didn’t provide accurate results due to deduplication, hardlinks, and symlinks employed by the system.
I’m sharing the solution here for future users who may encounter the same challenge. The method described below will help you calculate the apparent size of a backup task, giving you the actual space occupied on the disk.
Solution
To calculate the real disk space occupied by a backup task, you can use the --apparent-size option with du, which disregards the optimizations and gives you the actual size the backup task would occupy if stored without these enhancements.

SSH into your Synology NAS: ssh user@your_nas_ip

Switch to root:sudo -i

Navigate to the Active Backup for Business backup directory:
Typically, the location is: cd /volume1/ActiveBackupforBusiness/ActiveBackupData

Run the du command with --apparent-size: Replace FOLDER with
the folder name of your backup task: du -h --apparent-size FOLDER


Why This Method Works
The --apparent-size flag in du shows the size of files without accounting for filesystem-level storage optimizations like deduplication or hardlinks. This allows you to see the actual storage space that each backup would occupy, helping you understand how much real disk space is consumed by your backup tasks.

Split your "question" to real question and answer
